# Postman only runs half of the requests in my collection

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner

There are 107 requests in my collection folder (postman). This collection was running perfectly fine before with all 107 requests executed. Now, i only see half of the requests running in the collection folder and no error prompted anywhere.
is there a limit on how many requests you can run now? or what's the issue?

Comment: This usually happens if there are some script errors in yout test oder pre-request script. An other issue could be, that you are working with postman.setNextRequest() commands in combination with renamed/moved/deleted requests. 
However, Its quite hard to find the error without knowing your code.Please provide more informations to you question.

Comment: Try to execute the last running request from you run. The bug must be somewhere there or in the next request.

Comment: That's weird, there's definitely no limit on the number of requests you run.
Can you open Postman Console and then run the collection runner, there could be a possible issue with your script. Let me know if you see any errors there.

Comment: Thank you all for all your responses!! Much appreciated.
the error was from my side @DieGraueEminenz you were right..... the issue was with the postman.setNextRequest() command. I've renamed one of the request name without changing it in the setNextRequest.